# wamp not working in Windows 10

Tags: wamp

Aestan Tray Menu

Could not execute menu item (internal error)
Exception. could not perform service action
the service has not been started

Also my wamp icon is orange

Answer (score 1):

Open Task-Manager -> Services -> W3SVC  - Stop
This should stop the IIS service. It belongs to a group called iissvcs

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the

```
Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4
```

also known as VC11. [Download and Install from this link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30679)

If you are running 64bit windows download and install both the 32bit and 64bit versions of this runtime. Remember 64bit windows runs 32 bit apps as well as 64bit ones.

```
VSU_4\vcredist_x86.exe  (32bit)
VSU_4\vcredist_x64.exe  (64bit)
```

And

```
Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2008
```

also know as VC9 [Download and install from this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5582)

These are runtime libraries used by any C/C++ program compiled with Visual Studio, which the version of Apache is in WAMPServer 2.5. Also the wampmanager.exe need the VC9 runtime.

Download these one at a time, so download one and then install it. Then the second one etc. Do it like this because the downloaded installer has a very similiar name and its easy to get confused.

If you are running 32bit Windows just download and install the 32bit runtime.

Because you did not have this DLL when you ran the WAMPServer install, the Apache service will not have been registered. So once this runtime library is installed you will have to do the following to get the Apache service running. Using `wampmanager`, the icon in the system tray do :-

```
(left click) wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Install Service
```

The Apache service should now be available to start using

```
(left click) wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Start/Resume Service
```

Comment: Cannot install the apache services, please stop this application and try again

Comment: Your port 80 is actually used by SERVER: Microsoft IIS/10.0

Comment: Then if you are not using IIS uninstall it. You dont need it if you are not using it. Microsoft seem to install it by default on W10 for some unknown reason. You can find instructions of the internet with a quick google

Comment: I need it for other work and can't uninstall please give me another solotion

Comment: Then while you are working on WAMP stop the IIS process and all the other paraphanalia that comes with it.

Comment: how can stop the IIS process?

Comment: Not Found

HTTP Error 404 the request resource is not found

Comment: That look like a different question. I assume WAMPSever (Apache and MySQL) are now running right?

Comment: No not working still an error while I am trying to open localhost unable to connect